# Splitting array in string does not give last element

Tags: java, arrays, string

Hi I am splitting and storing string with use of array but does not give result

```
String str = "123456";
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split("");

        String otpnum1 = arrOfStr[0];
        String otpnum2 = arrOfStr[1];
        String otpnum3 = arrOfStr[2];
        String otpnum4 = arrOfStr[3];
        String otpnum5 = arrOfStr[4];
        String otpnum6 = arrOfStr[5];

        System.out.println("otp"+otpnum1+otpnum2+otpnum3+otpnum4+otpnum5+otpnum6);
```

OUTPUT

System.out: otp12345

Comment: This code outputs `otp123456`

Comment: It prints `otp123456`, you can check here https://repl.it/repls/UnrealisticHarmfulSystems

Comment: What problem you are facing? Your program producing expected result

Comment: It's correctly print otp123456. what is your desired result?

Comment: my desired result is 123456, I post output what i am getting , so my question is why it is giving me such result

Comment: i checked again still its System.out: otp 12345, please check in android studio

Answer (score 0):

You are printing without any space or newline, which is the reason you are not able to interpret individual variables. Use this

```
System.out.println("otp " + otpnum1+ " " + otpnum2+" " + " "+ otpnum3+ " " + otpnum4+ " " + otpnum5+ " " + otpnum6);
```

Comment: System.out: otp  1  2 3 4 5

Answer (score 0):

I understand, the output is 12345, and expected 123456 for the result.

But, looking your code looks like correct.
I have try your code here, for test, and works fine.

The output was: **otp123456**

Comment: System.out: otp  1  2 3 4 5

Comment: can you suggest any other way to split and store in string

Comment: can you try, print only otpnum6? to see if he has value, or better, debugging e and observing the values in the moment of print result